# Django Admin javascript loads but does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I took this file from https://jsfiddle.net/emkey08/zgvtjc51 try with my **Django admin**.
the code is

```
if (!$) {
    $ = django.jQuery;
}
$(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  };
}(django.jQuery));


$("#id_fin").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value); });
```

Now this code loads but does not work, but works from console. There were others who faced the same issue and as the suggested answers were to move the script to end of DOM. 
`change_form.html`was extended as below.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}{{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'prop/js/number_validate.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Still the end result is the same. Can someone suggest something.

```js
$.fn.inputFilter = function (inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function () {
        if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
            this.oldValue = this.value;
            this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
            this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
        } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
            this.value = this.oldValue;
            this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
        }
    });
};

$(function () {

    $("#id_fin").inputFilter(function (value) {
        return /^\d*$/.test(value);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Integer (both positive and negative  123):<input id="id_fin">
```

Comment: Just for information I  am using Django 2.2

Comment: Moved it and checked, same issue...After suggested change runs in console but not when the page loads up.

Comment: @gaetanoM I just ran one  #id_fin.inputfilter in console and and that works. so I suppose there is nothing wrong with the function part.

Comment: Really new to html and js, how do I create a snippet. I am using safari

Comment: I created one for you updating your question. Run the snippet and let me know if you get some error.  Thanks

Comment: Wow it works and would you believe it, I wasted at least 4-5 hours working on it.
Thanks a Ton.............

Comment: If y0u will add the answer then I will accept it.

Comment: does not matter. I am happy you solved your issue. Thanks